# All unregistered domains are being redirected to the same IP. What does this mean?

Tags: troubleshooting

Whenever I make a request to an unregistered URL, I receive a 301 response code and I'm redirected to a specific IP. For example, in response to `http GET http://dsfijewijfeif.com`
I get:

```sh
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 169
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 20 May 2020 19:36:08 GMT
Location: https://backups.vc/
Server: nginx/1.16.1
```

This happens regardless of browser, only on my PC and not in any other device on the same connection. If I force https, firefox complains about an invalid certificate:

```
 Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for dsifjdifjeifejfliejefije.com. The certificate is only valid for www.backups.vc.
```

Comment: What are your DNS servers ?

Comment: DNS is the place to look or your hosts file. Another option might be a firefox plugin redirecting you when a domain name doesn't exist. Perhaps a bit of malware or similar.